# What value does $(shell pwd) give?

Tags: linux, bash, makefile

Going through a MakeFile I find

`PROJECT_ROOT = $(shell pwd)`

What value does it give?

`$SHELL` gives the shell and `$PWD` gives present working directory
But what does $(shell pwd) give?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `$(shell)` function calls out to the shell to execute a command.  The command being executed in this case is `pwd`, like if you ran `pwd` at the bash shell prompt.

So, `$(shell pwd)` will return the current working directory.  You may not be guaranteed that the `$PWD` variable exists in your make environment.